# Button to connect a single Bluetooth device on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I have a pair of Bluetooth headphones paired to both my phone and laptop. I frequently switch between the two.

Sometimes the headphones won't auto-connect to my laptop when disconnecting from my phone, and I need to open the settings and do it manually. This isn't a problem but about of clicks.

Trying to find a way that I can pin the specific device to connect either from the start menu. I couldn't find anything when searching. Is this possible?

Wondering if I can use a .bat file to do it.

Comment: I do not think that it can be possible with just a bat or cmd file but probably with PowerShell script. If you are more or less OK with programming all you need to do is just to call one function: BluetoothSetServiceState() for yuor device when needs to switch to it.

Comment: Thanks! I've worked with powershell before (made a script to mass-setup Android devices). I'll look into that!

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> opens a sidebar with wireless connections where you can connect/disconnect your devices with one click.

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem, here's my solution:

https://github.com/stanleyguevara/win10-bluetooth-headphones

You can then bind `connect.vbs` `disconnect.vbs` or `toggle.vbs` to some media key, like described [here](https://visser.io/2017/11/remap-the-calculator-keyboard-key-to-playpause-on-windows-10/)

Mind you it requires third-party software to work, and `toggle.vbs` is a bit slow because it needs to check what's the actual state of connection, but hey, it works with one button!